# More elegant way to store bits in a byte in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I want to use 5 boolean values in a byte variable in C#. I have come up with the below code which works fine, but it's rather ugly.

```
byte myDataMask = 0;
if (isOne) myDataMask |= 1;
if (isTwo) myDataMask |= 2;
if (isFour) myDataMask |= 4;
if (isEight) myDataMask |= 8;
if (isSixteen) myDataMask |= 16;
```

Is there a nicer, more elegant, **shorter** way to express the same?

Comment: There's the `BitArray` class.

Comment: If you don't want to go the `BitArray` route, just encapsulate your code in its own class and give it an indexer.

Answer (score 1):

How about an enumeration :

```
        public enum Mask
        {
            IS_NONE = 0,
            IS_ONE = 1,
            IS_TWO = 2,
            IS_FOUR = 4,
            IS_EIGHT = 8,
            IS_SIXTEEN = 16
        }
        private static void Main()
        {

            byte data = 0x04;

            switch ((Mask)data)
            {
                case Mask.IS_NONE :
                    break;

                case Mask.IS_ONE :
                    break;
                case Mask.IS_TWO :
                    break;
                case Mask.IS_FOUR :
                    break;
                case Mask.IS_EIGHT :
                    break;
                case Mask.IS_SIXTEEN :
                    break;


            }


        }
```

Comment: Doesn't MS advise to use the `[Flags]` attribute for bit flags (even though it doesn't admittedly do anything)?

Comment: Side note: `public enum Mask: byte {...}` if we want `enum` to be `byte`, not `Int32`

Comment: MS also advises to use PascalCase for enum members (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).